# Ajax not working in jsf view

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

In a JSF Primefaces / PrimefacesExtension app, i have some ajax misbehaviour.

There is a section of the view, only shown when a condition is true:

```
<h:form id="membership" rendered="#{empty registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate}">
```

Inside, there are 2 grids: first one with red text and a button to make action (pay a membership), this first grid will dissapear when action done, and a second one will be shown:

```
    <p:panelGrid id="not_paid" layout="grid" columns="2" rendered="#{!registerVisitBean.paid}">
        <h:outputText value="No pagada" styleClass="data-text red"  />
        <p:commandButton value="Pagar" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.payMembership}" update="paid,not_paid" />
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:panelGrid id="paid" layout="grid" columns="1" rendered="#{registerVisitBean.paid}">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate}" styleClass="data-text" />
    </p:panelGrid>
```

The view is quite long, but other parts have independent forms and are not important here... The `<form>` tag is NOT nested inside other `<form>` but it is in other `<p:panelGrid>`, but not a problem i think, this is happening in same view to change the color of an element after making action and works perfect:

```
<h:form id="notes">
<p:panelGrid id="partner_notes" layout="grid" columns="1" >
    <p:inputTextarea value="#{registerVisitBean.partnerNotes}" id="notes" rows="2" autoResize="false" styleClass="#{registerVisitBean.saved ? 'full-width unresizable success' : 'full-width unresizable'}" style="padding: 0"></p:inputTextarea>
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar Notes" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.updateNotes}" styleClass="full-width" update=":notes:partner_notes"/>
</p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I think problem is in the `update` part of the `<p:commandButton>` but i've tried several ways without succeed.

**NOTE:** bean code is being executed:

```
private boolean paid; 
// ( getter / setter)

public void payMembership(){
    MembershipDto membership =  partner.getActiveMembership();
    membership.setPayDate(new Date());
    membership.setMember(partner);
    membership = partnerManagementFacade.updateMembership(membership);
    if (membership != null){
        System.err.println("Paid > " + membership.getPayDate());
        paid = true;
    }
}
```

With java code there is no problem, debugging shows all goes correct, but after the view is not refreshed.

**EDIT1:** according to @stg answer, i tried unsuccesfully:

```
<p:outputPanel id="container">
<p:panelGrid id="not_paid" layout="grid" columns="2" rendered="#{!registerVisitBean.paid}">
    <h:outputText value="No pagada" styleClass="data-text red"  />
    <p:commandButton value="Pagar" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.payMembership}" update="container" />
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid id="paid" layout="grid" columns="1" rendered="#{registerVisitBean.paid}">
    <h:outputText value="#{registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate}" styleClass="data-text" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

As his answer says:

> You can not update a component, that has not been rendered previously, because it is "just not there"!

I think with his code, the problem will persist (second panel grid is not being rendered first time, so I cannot update update it cause it doesn't exists.

Trying to avoid this problem i decided to update the `<p:outputText>` and remove the `<p:commandButton>` from the view:

```
<h:form id="membership">
    <h:panelGroup id="not_paid" layout="block" rendered="#{empty registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate}">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerVisitBean.paid ? registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate : 'No pagada'}" styleClass="data-text red"  />
        <p:commandButton value="Pagar" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.payMembership}" update="not_paid,@this" rendered="#{!registerVisitBean.paid}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Instead of expected... this is not working either. :'(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can not repaint a wall you never built!

Here: You can not update a component, that has not been rendered previously, because it is "just not there"!

What you may do is nest your panelgrid in a surrounding outputpanel and update this outputpanel instead of the grids:

```
<p:outputPanel id="container">
    <p:panelGrid id="not_paid" layout="grid" columns="2" rendered="#{!registerVisitBean.paid}">
        <h:outputText value="No pagada" styleClass="data-text red"  />
        <p:commandButton value="Pagar" actionListener="#{registerVisitBean.payMembership}" update="container" />
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:panelGrid id="paid" layout="grid" columns="1" rendered="#{registerVisitBean.paid}">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerVisitBean.partner.activeMembership.payDate}" styleClass="data-text" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: This is not working, check my edit in original question please. :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla If this does not work, then there must be an *addtional* unrelated problem within your code. Check what is beeing return when you call registerVisitBean.paid (e.g. by putting some System.out in the getter method) ... probably your bean class is defective as well. You should provide the code of the bean (including the used import statements etc)

Comment: true, the method `public void payMembership()` is being executed only one time... but no errors shown :( i must investigate more...